# Comparing the contents of two Treemaps

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have two TreeMaps that I want to compare.
I currently have it written down like below but I feel like this could be written more efficiently. I tried looking in to comparators, but I don't think that's something I can use for my use-case.

The maps are Treemaps because the key must be case-insensitive.

```java
public void theseRulesAreTheSame() {
    List<String> failures = new ArrayList<>();

    TreeMap<String, NSG> configNsgs = platformConfiguration.getAzure().nsgs();
    configNsgs.forEach((name, nsg) -> {
      assertThat(azureAdapter.doesNsgExistInAzure(name))
          .as("Unable to find network security group " + name + " in Azure.").isTrue();

      List<SecurityRulesItem> configSecurityRules = nsg.getSecurityRules();
      TreeMap<String, Object> azureSecurityRules = azureAdapter
          .getSecurityRulesForNsg(name);

      assertThat(configSecurityRules.size())
          .as("The nymber of security rules in Azure does not correspond to the number of security rules in the configuration!")
          .isEqualTo(azureSecurityRules.size());

      configSecurityRules.forEach(configSecurityRule -> {
        SecurityRuleInner azureSecurityRule = (SecurityRuleInner) azureSecurityRules
            .get(configSecurityRule.getRuleName());

        logger.info(
            "Checking security rule " + configSecurityRule.getRuleName()
                + " in network security group "
                + nsg.getName());

        if (null == azureSecurityRule) {
            logFailure(failures, null, configSecurityRule.getRuleName());
        } else {
          if (!azureSecurityRule.access().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getAccess())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getAccess(), azureSecurityRule.access());
          }
          if (!azureSecurityRule.destinationAddressPrefix().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getDestinationAddressPrefix())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getDestinationAddressPrefix(), azureSecurityRule.destinationAddressPrefix());
          }
          if (!azureSecurityRule.destinationPortRange().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getDestinationPortRange())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getDestinationPortRange(), azureSecurityRule.destinationPortRange());
          }
          if (!azureSecurityRule.sourceAddressPrefix().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getSourceAddressPrefix())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getSourceAddressPrefix(), azureSecurityRule.sourceAddressPrefix());
          }
          if (!azureSecurityRule.sourcePortRange().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getSourcePortRange())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getSourcePortRange(), azureSecurityRule.sourcePortRange());
          }
          if (!azureSecurityRule.protocol().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getProtocol())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getProtocol(), azureSecurityRule.protocol());
          }
          if (!azureSecurityRule.direction().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(configSecurityRule.getDirection())) {
            logFailure(failures, configSecurityRule.getDirection(), azureSecurityRule.direction());
          }
        }
      });
    });
    if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
      Assertions.fail(
          "Error(s) detected while comparing the network security groups between Azure and the config. Failures: "
              + failures);
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see a TreeMap in your question, just comparing the fields of two objects.

Comment: Sorry, didn't copy the whole method.

Comment: Note that this community isnt intended to **review** working code. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ *might* be a better place.

Comment: The first version was fine if the initial code snippet was the part you wanted to improve. Can you be more specific about what you think might be inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have the two types `AzureSecurityRule` and `ConfigSecurityRule` we could make the comparison less verbose like this:

```
 BiConsumer<AzureSecurityRule, ConfigSecurityRule>  compareField(Function<AzureSecurityRule,String> f1, Function<ConfigSecurityRule> f2) {
return (az, cf) -> {
    if !f1.apply(az).equalsIgnoreCase(f2.apply(cf)) {
      logFailure(failure, f2.apply(cf), f1.apply(az));
    }
  }
}
...
List.of(
  compareField(az -> az.access().toString(), cf -> cf.getAccess()),
  compareField(az -> az.destinationAddressPrefix(), cf -> cf.getDestinationAddressPrefix()),
  ...
).forEach(cf -> cf.accept(azureSecurityRule, configSecurityRule));
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, going to read up on BiConsumer